# Como retirar uma parte de uma string?

Tags: java, string

Tenho um texto guardado em uma string e preciso copiar uma parte desse texto ao 
encontrar uma determinada palavra nele.

Ex.: 
Preciso retirar meu nome e minha idade desse texto, eu sei que eles sempre vem após : e entre aspas.

```
String texto = "Meu nome: "+ "Mariane Teixeira" + ", Minha idade: "+ "22";

//resposta
String nome = "Mariane Teixeira"
String idade = "22"
```

Posso usar como FLAG os : ou "" ou a palavra "nome" e "idade" e copiar o que vem depois deles, mas não sei como fazer isso utilizando código java.

Comment: Tentou fazer algo ja?

Comment: Essa string que você criou possui algum erro de sintaxe!

Comment: @Articuno não... eu estou com a lógica na mente mas não sei passar isso para código. Não conheço muito bem as bibliotecas de string

Comment: @white a string é "Meu nome: "Mariane Teixeira",  Minha idade: "22"

Comment: @MariTeixeira mesmo assim, isso não compila. Você tem que colocar exatamente como está no seu código, se estiver no seu código. Tente descrever melhor seu problema.

Comment: Não é mais interessante utilizar o formato `JSON`?

Comment: @white String texto = "Meu nome: "+ "Mariane Teixeira" + ", Minha idade: "+ "22";

Comment: @MariTeixeira seria interessante você deixar na sua pergunta, exatamente como está no seu código. Se quiser, você mesmo pode editar e corrigir isso lá.

Comment: Se você está já está contatenando, porque você quer desconcatenar? hehe =)

Comment: Se existe um padrão use expressões regulares

Comment: Que parte exatamente vc precisa copiar desse texto? Somente retirar todas ocorrências de determinada string? Ou somente copiar oq vem antes, ou somente o que vem depois?

Comment: preciso só o que vem depois dos dois pontos. são várias informações, nome: ........, idade: ..........., endereço: .......... preciso dessas informações

Comment: Faça o seguinte. Como está seu arquivo? Ele tem um formato padronizado ou está irregular? Que atributos existem no seu arquivo? Ou precisa somente dos que descreveu (nome, idade, endereço)?

Para um resposta correta e necessário que vc edite a pergunta e coloque uma parte do seu arquivo nela.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode utilizar uma expressão regular para extrair os valores da sua `String`:

```
([^,\:]+)\:([^\,]+)
```

Esta expressão regular irá procurar qualquer sequência de 1 ou mais caracteres que não sejam `,` nem `:` (`([^,\:]+)`) seguido por `:` (`\:`) que possua qualquer sequência de um ou mais caracteres que não contenham `,` (`([^\,]+)`). No `Java` escapamos os caracteres especiais da expressão regular com duas barras (`\\`). Portanto cheguei no seguinte método que transforma sua `String` em um `Map`:

```
public static Map<String, String> separar(String texto) {
  String regex = "([^,\\:]+)\\:([^\\,]+)";
  Map<String, String> resultado = new HashMap<>();

  Pattern parte = Pattern.compile(regex);
  Matcher matcher = parte.matcher(texto);

  while (matcher.find()) {
    String chave = matcher.group(1);
    String valor = matcher.group(2);

    resultado.put(chave.trim(), valor.trim());
  }

  return resultado;
}
```

Você pode testar o método com a sua `String` da seguinte forma:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  String texto = "Meu nome: Mariane Teixeira, Minha idade: 22";

  Map<String, String> valores = separar(texto);

  valores.forEach((chave, valor) -> System.out.println(chave + ": " + valor));
}
```

O valor impresso no `console` seria o seguinte:

> ```
> Meu nome: Mariane Teixeira
> Minha idade: 22
> ```

---

Algumas observações:

- Sua `String` está muito parecida com a notação de um [`JSON`](http://www.json.org/json-pt.html), embora não represente um `JSON` válido. Sendo assim, considere utilizá-la.
- No seu exemplo você utilizou o código `"Meu nome: "+ "Mariane Teixeira" + ", Minha idade: "+ "22"` para gerar a `String`. O resultado seria `"Meu nome: Mariane Teixeira, Minha idade: 22"`. Caso queira colocar os valores entre aspas a atribuição deveria ser `"Meu nome: \"Mariane Teixeira\", Minha idade: \"22\""`.

Answer (score 1):

Uma forma bem preguiçosa de resolver:

```
String text = "Meu nome: \"Mariane Teixeira\", Minha idade: \"22\"";
String [] textArray = text.split("\"");

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(textArray));

System.out.println("Meu nome: " + textArray[1]);
System.out.println("Minha idade: " + textArray[3]);
```